# Pressing back button stops app during Camera activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, back-button

I capture photo and save into my Gallery. Everything works perfect when I capture an image and save. But if the camera is on and if I press the back button without taking a picture then the application stops.

How I can solve this issue?

This is my code:

```
public class ImportCard extends Activity {

private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;
ImageButton importimage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_import_card);

ImageButton importimage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.importimage);
importimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }
    });    
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        //2
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
        //3
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        //4
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //5
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapcard"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" /> 

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/vcard"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.NewCard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_card" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.ImportCard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_import_card">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.CardBox"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_card_box" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.QRCode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_card" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.Template"
        android:label="@string/title_template" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.DisplayCard"
        android:label="@string/title_display_card" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.GoogleMap"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.ViewCard"
        android:label="@string/title_view_card" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.QRScan"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_import_card" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.ViewTemplates"
        android:label="@string/title_view_templates" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapcard.SendEmail"
        android:label="@string/title_send_email" >
    </activity>


</application>
```

Error in my LogCat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result

Error on my device:

> Unfortunately, App has stopped

Comment: What you want to do when back button pressed?

Comment: I just want to go back to activity, it is supposed to be the normal function of the mobile device.

Comment: use on backpressed method to release camera with super.onBackPressed()

Comment: could you mention it as an answer? with some explanation pls? Because what i know is onBackPressed is an option for Android buttons not device. Thx

Comment: What do you mean by "Application stops"? Is there some error in the system log?

Comment: @AlexCohn i edited my question to mention what errors i have received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking only requestCode. You should check the value of resultCode also. When the user has successfully performed the action, the resultCode will be equal to RESULT_OK. If the user presses the back button then the resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED. So your code must be modified like this.

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:noHistory="false"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml for that activity

Comment: I guess @akashsr suspects something real... Would you like to post your `AndroidManifest.xml`, please?

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml` is inserted

Answer (score -1):

In `onActivityResult` you should check whether `thumbnail` is null, and if so just return.

Edit: like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ...
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    if (extras == null || extras.get("data") == null) return;

    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    ...  
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for editing. But this didnt save me from the issue. Still same problem.

Comment: See my edited code, now also checking whether the extras bundle is null.

Comment: In general, a stacktrace from logcat would be helpful.